# COUNT and delete of the number of duplicates from table with billion rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to know how many duplicate rows are in a table which has a billion rows

And then I need to delete these by chunks if possible.

This table has 32 columns and I want to check if there are any repeated rows with the same values in all the 32 columns.

I have tried 1)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM 
    (SELECT COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3....COLUMN32 ,COUNT(*)
     FROM TABLE 
     GROUP BY COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3....COLUMN32
     HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

and 2)

I have also tried with ROW_NUMBER

> Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.SORT temporary run storage:
> 141881590939648' in database 'tempdb' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup
> is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping
> objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or
> setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup

This takes forever and this fail with tempdb error.

Comment: I can only hope and assume that you mean all the columns except for the primary key column(s). But why not a simple count(*) - count(distinct col1, col2, col3, col4...)?

Comment: BTW, the error message in the your second query is pretty clear. You ran out of allocate-able disc space for tempdb because you are sorting so many rows.

Comment: There is no primary key on this table,the aim is to add a primary key after deleting duplicates.Can you do count(distinct col1,col2 etc..) its not a valid syntax

Comment: Ouch!!! A billion row heap table. I hope you have a lot of disc space, this is not going to be fast and it is going to inhale disc space.

Comment: This is unlikely, but do you have enough room on your disk for a second full copy of the table?

Comment: yes I do have disk space.

Comment: It sounds like you still have a disk space issue wherever tempdb is stored otherwise tempdb wouldn't get allocation failures. For the problem table you could add a column to store `checksum(Column1, Column2, ..., Column32)` (persist this, don't make it a computed column), add a nonclustered (non-unique) index on it then start deleting the duplicate rows in smaller batches of say 10,000 rows at a time. Once deduplicated you can drop the checksum column. REF: [CHECKSUM (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the below

```
SELECT -COUNT_BIG(*) Dup
into #T
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Table.*
    FROM Table
) X

Insert into #T
SELECT COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM Table

SELECT SUM(DUP)
FROM #T

DROP TABLE #T
```

Took few hours to run as this table has billions of records.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to delete all repeated record and then insert one record for each different record

```
SELECT *
INTO #A
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, ... COLUMN32
HAVING COUNT(*)>1

DELETE T
FROM TABLE AS T
INNER JOIN #A AS A ON T.COLUMN1 = A.COLUMN1 AND T.COLUMN2 = A.COLUMN3 AND ... AND T.COLUMN32 = A.COLUMN32

INSERT INTO TABLE
SELECT *
FROM #A

DROP TABLE #A
```

If you get error for big data use `SELECT TOP(10000) * INTO #A` and run this code multiple this to delete a few extra records each time.